# How sum values in days intervals MySQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sum, pivot

I have a server with MySQL 5.7.
I have two tables. First one `t` contains creating dates for each id. Second table `t0` contains profit records day by day for each id.
I want to get columns with sums of profit for first and second 30 days for each id as well as for the first day.

```
SELECT t.created_at,
   t.id,
   sum(t1.profit) profit_1_week,
   sum(t2.profit) profit_2_week,
   sum(t3.profit) profit_1_day
FROM t
LEFT JOIN t0 t1 ON t.id = t.id
AND t1.inport_date BETWEEN t.created_at AND DATE_ADD(t.created_at, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
LEFT JOIN t0 t2 ON t.id = t.id
AND t2.inport_date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(t.created_at, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(t.created_at, INTERVAL 60 DAY)
LEFT JOIN t0 t3 ON t.id = t.id
AND t3.inport_date BETWEEN t.created_at AND DATE_ADD(t.created_at, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY t.created_at,
         t.id
ORDER BY t.created_at
```

This code runs but sums are wrong because sum of the first day much more then monthly. Where I'm wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: t.Id is always the same as t.Id in your on clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem statement is not that clear, but based on your attempt, I suspect that you can do conditional aggregation:

```
select t.created_at, t.id, 
    sum(case when t0.inport_date >= t.created_at                   and t0.inport_date < t.created_at + interval 30 day then t0.profit else 0 end) profit_1,
    sum(case when t0.inport_date >= t.created_at + interval 30 day and t0.inport_date < t.created_at + interval 60 day then t0.profit else 0 end) profit_2,
    sum(case when t0.inport_date >= t.created_at                   and t0.inport_date < t.created_at + interval  1 day then t0.profit else 0 end) profit_3
from t
left join t0 on t0.id = t.id 
group by t.created_at, t.id
order by t.created_at
```

The logic is to join just once, and then to use `case` expressions within the `sum()`s to choose which values should be taken into account.

I changed the date filtering logic to use half-open intervals rather than `between`, because it seems more relevant to me. You can adapt that as you wish according to your actual use case.